How to save the last 2 chars of a const char* string to a char* var in c?
(Imagine a simple program that lets user input a word, and print the last two letters. that's it)
i'm trying to copy the last 2 chars of a (const char *) string to a (char *) in c. Not allowed to change input and last type.
Below is what i tried. (made some edit according to comments)
int lasttwo(const char *input, char *last){
    strcpy(last, input + strlen(input) - 2) ; // need to change this line
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
    for(int i = 1, i < argc; i++ {
    char *buf = NULL;
    int result = lasttwo(argv[i], buf);
    printf("last two letter of '%s' is '%s'", argv[i], buf) ;

 }
}

return 0;


this led to error when compiling
 error: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Werror,-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    last =  input + strlen(input)-2;
         ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

how to get the last two letters out with changing last type?

To point to an element in a string of const char, use a const char *, not char *. If you need to use a char * but are not going to modify the characters, it is possible to cast the type. But the right solution depends on context and criteria. You have not provided enough information about what you are trying to do.

"Save" as in "copy to new string" or just "get pointer to"?

When asking questions about build errors, first make sure you show us a proper [mre]. And then copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build output into the question. And add a comment on the line in the code where you get the error.

char *'s do not contain/hold chars. They can point to buffers (arrays of chars) that contain chars. 2 possibilities here. 1) provide a big enough buffer, set the pointer last to point to the buffer, copy the last 2 chars and null terminator from the first buffer into this buffer; 2) Set the pointer last to point into the proper place in the buffer pointed to by input. In this case, since input is a const char *, last should properly also be a const char *.

When I clean it up works for me, with only a warning about losing the const qualifier (which should certainly be addressed). Do you have -Werror compiler flag set?

@EricPostpischil the var types are not allowed to be changed (they were passed to here). how do i get the two letters out in  the char* last? (the goal is just to print out the two letters)

@AviBerger thank you. how to actually do 1)? im not sure about the null terminator side. (new to c, coming from python)

@yano i did the same and encounter error while compiling " error: assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Werror,-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
last =  input + strlen(input)-n;
^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated."

Wrt the definition of proper, what do you think the user wants if strlen(input) < 2?

That error message should be in the question .. but yes the problem is that -Werror flag. That treats all warnings as errors, so that's why it's failing to build. You either need to make last a const char* type (this is the preferred fix) or drop the -Werror flag from your build procedure.

@yano any suggestion to how to fix it? without this line the program compiles. this line is the only problem

@yano im not allowed to change last type. how to drop -werror flag?

What is your actual assignment? What are its requirements? What are its limitations? Please [edit] your question to give us all relevant information, about the errors and the assignment.

I don't know, that depends on how you're building. Makefile? CMake? Invoking gcc/clang directly? If you're sending this code to some auto-grading server then there's probably nothing you can do but talk to the prof. You'll need to provide more details about how you're building to get an answer.

Your words "the var types . . . (they were passed to here)" could affect things, as they hint at stuff that you haven't shown us. They could be read to imply that the variables are actually function parameters, that you are in a function, and that last is already pointing to a provided output buffer to use. We can't tell if that is the case from your post. If you are provided an output buffer, you don't want to try and create yet another one.

@AviBerger yes this is inside a function that has only 2 parameters, const char* input and char *last.

I'm failing to see what purpose last serves, a [mre] would certainly help. If you assign it in the function, the only way for that assignment to persist outside of the function is to return it. If you just need to print the last 2 letters in the function, then ok? In either case, you don't even need the last argument.

You need that in your post, as it makes things different. It also strongly implies that in the problem specification you are told that last points to a buffer/char array of some size. That is also critical information that needs to be included in your post. You may need to look up the strcpy library function.

you can do some hacky things like this to suppress the warnings, but like I said I'm failing to see what purpose last serves

@yano I'm guessing that last points to a caller provided output buffer. Otherwise, as you say, it would be useless.

@yano added more context in code

this is broken on multiple levels. Your function returns an int (always 0 in fact). lasttwo has no hope of returning the last 2 chars. If this is an assignment template you need some serious clarification from your instructor, what you've posted makes absolutely no sense.

That at least needs to be char* lasttwo(...) { return last; } and in main, buf = lasttwo(...); printf("%s .. %s\n", argv[i], buf);, but that still won't fix your warning-turned-to-error about discarding the const qualifier.

@yano you were right. i made some mistake when simplfying the program . code is updated

void lasttwo(const char *in, char *out) { strcpy(out, in + strlen(in) - 2); } and char last[3]; lasttwo(argv[i], last);

After your most recent edit, the error message you posted no longer corresponds to the code that you posted. Please update the error message after changing the code.

I don't know your experience level, so I'll be a little basic here.
This declaration is a pointer to a constant array of characters - that is, you're not allowed to change the characters:
const char * cs = "Don't change me";

That means this is an error:
cs[2] = 'x';  // Compiler error

You can also specify const for an array:
    const char ca[] = "Don't change me";
    ca[2] = 'x'; // Compiler error

Without const, the arrays are mutable
    char a[] = "Change me";
    char * s = a;
    a[2] = 'x';  // Allowed
    s[2] = 'y';  // Allowed

You can't mix them, otherwise you could change a constant.
    const char ca[] = "Don't change me";
    char * s = a; // Warning because of below
    ca[2] = 'x';  // Compiler error
    s[2] = 'y';   // Allowed but should not be

That's the background. That is also what you're trying to do your function lasttwo(). But your description says you're trying to copy characters, not change the pointer.
You can copy characters with strcpy() (you should actually use strncpy() or a similar safer variant, but I will assume you are certain that input is a correct string). Copying the last two characters would look like this.
    const char * input = "Input string";
    char last[2];
    strcpy(last, input + strlen(input) - 2);  // Not quite right

This is an error, because strcpy() will copy the last 2 characters, but also the terminating '\0' for a total of 3 characters. So you need to declare char last[3]; with the extra space.
Assuming that's what you actually want to do, and assuming the parameters passed in are declared correctly, part of the confusion is because you're changing the parameters to lasttwo(), but since parameters are local to a function, this will have no effect when the function returns. For example:
    void f(int i) {
        i++;
    }
    
    // ...called from here
    int i = 2;
    f(i);
    printf("i = %d\n", i);  // Prints 2, not 3

It's useful to make the arguments to a function constant as a reminder that changes are local. You can declare a pointer to be constant by putting const after the *.
const char * cs = "Can't change this";
const char * const ccs = "Also can't change this";

cs = ccs;  // Allowed, cs can be changed and both point to const char
ccs = cs;  // Compiler error, ccs can't be changed to anything.

If my assumptions are correct, your function would look like this:
int lasttwo(const char * const input, char * const last){
    strcpy(last, input + strlen(input) - 2)
    return 0;
}

When the function is called, it needs to be passed an array to contain the returned characters, not a pointer:
    char buf[3];
    lasttwo(input, buf);


very clear and helpful! i came from python and the difference between c/c++ python is a lot more than i anticipated..took a lot of wrong assumptions. thank you and thank folks who commented above.

@jazzfaz I see, so you were probably thinking of slices, which is a language concept that came after C. Newer languages such as Zig have slices.

I don't think that it is appropriate to describe strncpy as a "safer variant" of strcpy. The function strncpy is highly dangerous, because it does not always write a null terminating character to the destination string. For example, char buffer[4]; strncpy(buffer, "test", 4); will copy the string without the null character to buffer. Using snprintf with the %s specifier is safer, because it will write a null character in that case (it will write tes\0 to buffer).

@AndreasWenzel I wrote "safer" and not "safe" because it's not safe, but I only wanted to raise the issue, not go into detail. Your comment is helpful for expanding on it though, so thanks.

It may be helpful to explain in more detail what the difference is between const char * const and char * const, given the constraints of the problem described by the asker, who is working with const char * and char *.
